# Bitwise operation on decimal datatype in .NET

Tags: .net, bit-manipulation, decimal, 128-bit

I just learned that `decimal` datatype is represented by 128 bits in .NET

Is it possible to do bitwise operations on `decimal`, and will that be any faster/slower than doing the operation on 2 `ulong`?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Doing bitwise operations on two ulongs makes sense, but on a decimal, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. First, [`decimal` is a floating-point type with base 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal), **not** a 128-bit integer. You can't do bitwise operations on floating-point types

Second, there's no 128-bit architecture out there, so even if you managed to have a 128-bit integer type in C# then it's in no way faster than operating on 2 `ulong` variables as you still have to break the 128-bit value into smaller pieces that fit into the register

---

That said, most modern PC architectures have [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) support so it's possible to have fast bitwise operations on a 128-bit type. It's very easy in native code but I'm not sure if you can do that in C# or not. If not then you must write a native code library and call it from C#.

Nevertheless in C# there's the [BitArray class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.7.2) that *may* use SIMD under the hood so try creating a 128-bit BitArray and see

In Mono there has long been [SIMD support](https://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html) with the [`Mono.Simd` namespace](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N:Mono.Simd'). Later when Microsoft developed RyuJit they introduced [`Microsoft.Bcl.Simd`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/04/22/c-vectorization-microsoft-bcl-simd/) for this purpose. It has now been renamed to [`System.Numerics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) which includes

> The SIMD-enabled vector types, which include [Vector2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Vector3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Vector4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector4?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Matrix3x2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix3x2?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Matrix4x4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Plane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.plane?view=netframework-4.7.2), and [Quaternion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.quaternion?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Mono now also [supports the official `System.Numerics` namespace](https://www.mono-project.com/news/2016/12/20/system-numeric-vectors/). Unfortunately currently many types in that namespace don't have any support for bitwise operations so you may need to work around that using normal arithmetic operations. But the [`Vector<T>` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netstandard-2.1) do have `BitwiseAnd`, `BitwiseOr`, `ExclusiveOr`...

For more information read

- [Parallelism on a Single Core - SIMD with C#](https://instil.co/2016/03/21/parallelism-on-a-single-core-simd-with-c/)
- [SIMD in Depth - Performance and Cost in C# and C++](https://instil.co/2016/04/07/simd-performance-with-csharp-and-cpp/)
- [Will .NET ever do intelligent SIMD?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e75e01a-4e83-41f7-868f-effbed1ba492/will-net-ever-do-intelligent-simd?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Using `System.Numerics.Vector` for Graphics Programming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/using-system-numerics-vector-for-graphics-programming/)
- [System.Numerics.Vectors 'Vector<T>': is it basically just System.UInt128?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49662258/995714)
- [Performance Gains with Data Parallelism: Using SIMD Instructions from C#](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/05/24/performance-gains-with-data-parallelism-using-simd-instructions-from-c/)